# Seekbar and Seek functionality in J2ME

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp, mmapi

How to design seekbar and its functionality for Video/Audio Player in J2ME?

I've tried with Slider Component in LWUIT but it's not working perfectly.

Used Sample piece of code from WTK samples but it's too tough to design other components if we use J2ME Canvas.

Comment: What's not working properly with the LWUIT slider component?

Comment: well functionality starts like creatung thread and based on Player duration i have used sliderComponent but its not working exactly

Comment: I don't have a better answer. If you can't describe what isn't working with the Slider component I can't help.